# QCA9377 Drops Out and Can't Even Open WiFi Settings

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, shutdown, atheros

I have a Dell Inspiron 3593 with a QCA9377 wifi card running Ubuntu 20.04. I'm well aware that this card causes problems on Ubuntu, but I have one that I don't think has been asked about before on here (or seemingly anywhere else).

Seemingly randomly, my wifi will completely drop out, pings to 8.8.8.8 return nothing, and all connection is lost. My wifi registers in the top-right as online, and no problems appear to show up anywhere, except for the fact that literally no connection works. This seems like a firmware issue, but the weird thing is that if I try to open WiFi Settings from the Gnome tray panel, I can't, and my mouse glitches and moves at a sloth-like pace for a few seconds. Then nothing. I have to force reboot to get wifi back, and that always works.

A little while ago I created a small script to force remove and then add back the `ath10k_pci`, `ath10k_core`, and `ath` kernel modules. I ran it for the first time today, and, just as when I try to open WiFi Settings, my system lags for a few seconds and the terminal process hangs. This script does work when wifi is functioning (but has no effect, it worked before).

I should also mention that rebooting through Ubuntu fails, the system just hangs on the shutdown screen (I've literally left it for two hours before and it's stayed there), I have to force shutdown with the physical power button.

This issue occurs no matter what WiFi network I'm on. I presume some logs and the like will be needed, so please comment as to what I should add, I'm not experienced at all in debugging issues like these. If somebody could provide a solution, or potential fixes, or even just something I can do to fix the problem when it happens **without rebooting**, that would be amazing.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, resolved it by replacing the buggy firmware - here is [the solution](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1872128).

[Download](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/master/QCA9377/hw1.0/CNSS.TF.1.0/firmware-5.bin_CNSS.TF.1.0-00267-QCATFSWPZ-1)

Then remove firware-5 and firware-6 (save them somewhere safe just in case you need them) from /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/ and rename the downloaded file firmware-5 and place it in the /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/ folder. Reboot. Sorted.

You need to do this every time you update the kernel.